# Add yum repo to Sonatype Nexus Repository in Proxy mode

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

Im new with Nexus Repository ( using OSS 3.37 in RHEL 7.7). Im trying to add a simple Yum repo. What i do:

```
Name: TestRepo
Proxy > Remote Storage: "http://mirror.centos.org/centos/"
Storage > Blob Store: "default"
```

Finally URL to access will be http://<IP_OF_NEXUS>:8081/repository/TestRepo/

When i try to access by using the URL i got:

```
*This yum proxy repository is not directly browseable at this URL.*
```

I found in [DOC from Sonatype web](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/yum-repositories) same steps that i made.

I made the same steps using a APT repo and i can access using  http://<IP_OF_NEXUS>:8081/repository/UbuntuRepo/

Config:

```
Name: UbuntuRepo
Proxy > Remote Storage: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"
Storage > Blob Store: "default"
```